# FileUtils.copyFile() crashes the program when trying to copy an exe

Tags: java, fileutils

I have been trying a lot of different options for copying files in Java and none have been working. The one that I was using when I think I found the real issue was FileUtils. Here is the code

```
        public void createUSBButtonAction() throws IOException {

                for(Object obj: programList.getItems()){

                    File src = new File("C:\\Users\\JohnsonL\\Desktop\\flashTranserProj\\flashTransferProj\\src\\sample\\Installers\\" + obj.toString());
                    File dst = new File("D:/Test/" + obj.toString());
                    System.out.println(dst.getUsableSpace());
                    FileUtils.copyFile(src, dst);
            }
```

It works fine until I copy an exe file. When I do that the program stops responding and a prompt comes up saying the JDK stopped working and doesn't give me any errors.

If I have to switch to another form of copying files I will but I would like to stick with FileUtils

Comment: It is possible that your AV is interfering with the copy.

Comment: do proper exception handling and see what is the error you are getting . Why we are executing dst.getUsableSpace() before copying the Fiel to destination location?

Comment: Sorry the dst.getUsableSpace() was something from earlier. And it crashes before it throws any exceptions.

Comment: If JVM crashes there should be a crash/dump file that you can investigate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file copy was taking too long so it was stopping the rest of the program to copy the file over. I fixed this by copying the file on another thread.

Answer (score 3):

This is most likely caused by your operating system since you are on Windows. Possibly antivirus or system policy is preventing executable files being copied to `D:\` path.

`FileUtils.copyFile()` is just a copy operation which under the hood usually uses `FileChannel`. It will not process files differently based on their extension or type as it only reads and writes bytes.